# Ruby on Rails: Default template for actions in one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller that happens to use the same (rabl) template for each action.  Is there a way to render this template by default without having to put call `render 'name'` in each action?

Comment: You can put that template code in the application layout i guess.

Comment: No I can't.  My application has dozens of controllers.  I only want the code to run for one of them.  And I would still need a main template for each action, defeating the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create another layout for your particular controller. For example:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout "name"
  #...
end
```

Please see "2.2.14 Finding Layouts" in the [Rails Guides - Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

**UPDATE:**

The default render behavior is to render the view which has the same name of the action if no render view is assigned. To change the default behavior, you need to override the render method, for example:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  #...
  def render *args
    args = ["the_view_name_which_you_want_to_render"] if args == []
    super
  end
  # ...
end
```

You can move the method to the application controller if you want to override the render method in all controllers, but I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: And then when I don't call render in my action I get a missing template error because by default rails will look for a template with the action name.  It is the latter behavior that I'm trying to override by providing a template that all actions will use by default.  I was hoping there was a way to do that but by this point I'm thinking not.

Comment: Oh.. I got it. The default render behavior is to render the view which has the same name of action if no render view is assigned, but you want to override the original behavior. I would update my answer.